# How to integrate AzureDevops and Prometheus?

Tags: azure-devops, prometheus, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to connect AzureDevops and Prometheus. I know that I have to use exporter for this by checking the below link

https://github.com/webdevops/azure-devops-exporter

But how can I add this to my AzureDevops and what I need to do in order to connect it with Prometheus?

Comment: Where do you want to use this tool? In Azure DevOps or Prometheus? What information do you use this tool to integrate？

Comment: I want to know how to integrate AzureDevops and Prometheus